# Variation of coupon collector's problem?

Tags: probability, expected-value, coupon-collector

If I have n coupons to collect and I buy only 2n boxes, how many distinct types of coupons can I expect to have?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $X_i$ be a random variable whose value is $1$ if coupon $i$ is among the coupons you find and $0$ if it is not.  Then you are looking for $E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)$